# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, formato

Tengo un data frame con diversos numeros de identificacion y estoy intentado formatearlo en dos secciones, si tiene mas de 10 digitos el formato es: 123.456.789-0, si es diferente a 10 digitos (menos o mas) el formato es: 123.456.789 / 123.456.789.000

```
for i in range(0, len(mydataset_df.NIT)):
    print 'esto es i =', i
    number = int(mydataset_df.iloc[i]['NIT'])
    length = len(str(number))
    if length == 10:
        nit = number[:-1]
        dv = int(number[-1:])
        nit = format(int(identification), ',d').replace(',', ".")+ "-" + str(dv)
        mydataset_df.loc[i,'NIT'] = nit
        print nit
    else:
        number = format(int(number), ',d').replace(',', ".")
        mydataset_df.loc[i,'NIT'] = number
        print number
    print 'La cantidad de caracteres son:',length
    print mydataset_df.loc[i,'razon_social']
    print '-----------------------'
```

El mensaje de error es:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

:::::::::::Adjunto imagen de referencia:::::::::::::
[image: IMAGEN DE REFERENCIA]

Comment: cuando extraes el numero `number` lo conviertes a `int`. No puedes extraer un substring de un `int`. O bien no haces esa conversion al extraerlo, o bien lo conviertes de nuevo a `str` antes de aplicarle el `[:-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando defines `number = int(mydataset_df.iloc[i]['NIT'])` dispones de un número entero. En la siguiente línea, lo que haces con `length = len(str(number))` es obtener la longitud de la cadena compuesta por `number`. Sin embargo, fíjate que en ningún momento guardas esa cadena en ningún sitio. Por lo tanto dispones de un `number`de tipo entero y un `length` de tipo entero, ninguna cadena.

Como solución, antes de `nit = number[:-1]` deberías convertir el número en cadena. Por ejemplo, `str_number = str(number)`.